# Finding the Jordan Basis and the Canonical form corresponding to the Jordan basis

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 &0 \\ 2 &1 &3 \\ 5& 0 &4 \end{pmatrix}
I know that the Characteristic polynomial is : $$(t-4)^2(t-1)$$
I started with eigenvalues $λ=1$
 and got in the null space:
\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}

$λ=4$
 and got :

\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},

in $A- 4I$ 
and got

\begin{pmatrix} -1\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},

in $(A- 4I)^2$

Which vector(s) do I choose correctly  for the Jordan Basis?

I chose $[0,1,0],[1,0,1]$ and got $b_3$ as $A-4I[b_2] = [0,5,5]$

What procedures should I use for choosing the correct Jordan basis vectors?
Secondly am I right?

Lastly, How do I get the Canonical form "corresponding to the basis"?

is it \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 &4 &1 \\ 0& 0 &4 \end{pmatrix}
or  \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 &0 \\ 0 &4 &0 \\ 0& 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}
How do I set it up correctly?

Comment: Thats only for the canonical form is it not?

Comment: even better http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordan+form+%7B%7B4%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%2C3%7D%2C%7B5%2C0%2C4%7D%7D to guide oneself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you made a slight computational error: the $4$-eigenspace of $A$ is spanned by $(0,1,1)$, not $(0,-1,1)$. You correctly picked a vector $(1,0,1) \in \ker (A-4I)^2$ that doesn't belong to $\ker(A-4I)$, which let you construct the Jordan chain $((1,0,1),(A-4I)(1,0,1)) = ((1,0,1),(0,5,5))$. (This now works because $(0,5,5)$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $4$.)

Then you just place the Jordan chains as columns of the change of basis matrix (reading a chain backwards if you want $1$s on the superdiagonal):

$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0&1\\ 1&5&0 \\ 0&5&1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

And then we get

$$ P^{-1}AP = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 4 \end{pmatrix}.$$

If instead you chose

$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0\\ 5&0&1 \\ 5&1&0 \end{pmatrix},$$

you'd get

$$ P^{-1}AP = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: for $(A-4I)^2$ both vectors were not in the null space of A-4I, would either work?

Comment: Also does the order of block in P matter

Comment: @GuestCalc The other vector $(-1,1,0)$ would also work; you would get the chain $((-1,1,0),(0,-5,-5))$.

Comment: @GuestCalc The ordering of the blocks is arbitrary and depends on the ordering you chose when placing the Jordan chains as columns of $P$.

Comment: along with [0,1,0] for lamda = 1

Comment: @GuestCalc There are just two chains here, so there are only two permutations of these chains; these correspond to the two possible ways to permute the two Jordan blocks. One chain consists of the single eigenvector $(0,1,0)$ corresponding to $\lambda = 1$, and the other chain consists of the two generalized eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda = 4$.

Comment: I have a few more doubts, 1) Should I be worried that wolfram shows a different solution set , 2) Normally we choose the vector which isnt in A-4I, if $(A-4I)^2$ and A-4I have no overlapping we can choose either?

Comment: 1) The Jordan chain just looks different because they started with a different vector, namely $(1/5,-1/5,0) \in \ker (A-4I)^2$, to generate the chain. The choice is arbitrary. 2) There will always be overlapping: we always have the chain of inclusions $\{ 0 \} \subseteq \ker (A-\lambda I) \subseteq \ker (A- \lambda I)^2 \subseteq \ker (A- \lambda I)^3 \subseteq \cdots$